# Software Installment Hassle

Tags: java

I want to run Dr-java on windows 10 platform but it's not working. It's prompting the error that has been provided[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpT0q.png) as a file attachment.

Answer (score 1):

When you are installing DR-java, you need to have Java Runtime Environment installed(JRE).

But the JRE you set up on the path is either corrupted or not existed. Try reinstalling your JRE again. If it still doesn't work re-install your Dr-java once again.